# No module named v4.proto.omni

Tags: python, python-2.7, twisted, pysnmp

I have installed pysnmp-4.x.I am getting following error during running a SNMP program.

I am using pysnmpSE 3.5.2 now but getting same error. I found that pysnmpSE doesn't hav v4 module. I was suggested that following error should resolved if pySNMP SE 3.x is used.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\ggne0622\Desktop\Python\google-python-exercises\babynames\SimpleAgent.py", line 18, in <module>
    from twistedsnmp import agent, agentprotocol, bisectoidstore
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\twistedsnmp\agent.py", line 4, in <module>
    from twistedsnmp import datatypes
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\twistedsnmp\datatypes.py", line 7, in <module>
    from twistedsnmp.pysnmpproto import v2c,v1
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\twistedsnmp\pysnmpproto.py", line 13, in <module>
    from pysnmp.v4.proto.omni import v2c,v1, error, rfc1157, rfc1905
ImportError: No module named v4.proto.omni
```

Code:

`#!/usr/bin/env python`
`from twisted.internet.iocpreactor import reactor`
`from twisted.internet import error as twisted_error`
`from twistedsnmp import agent, agentprotocol, bisectoidstore`
`#from twisted.internet import interfaces`
`try:`
    `from twistedsnmp import bsdoidstore`
`except ImportError:`
    `import warnings`
    `warnings.warn( """No BSDDB OID Storage available for testing""" )`
    `bsdoidstore = None`

`def createAgent( oids ):`
    `ports = [161]+range(20000,25000)`
    `for port in ports:`
        `try:`

```
        `agentObject = reactor.IOCPReactor.listenUDP(port,`   `agentprotocol.AgentProtocol(snmpVersion = 'v2c',agent = agent.Agent(dataStore =`   `bisectoidstore.BisectOIDStore(OIDs = oids,),),),)`  
    `except twisted_error.CannotListenError:`  
        `pass`  
    `else:`  
        `return agentObject, port`
```

`testingOIDs = {`
    `'.1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0': 'Some tool out in the field',`
    `'.1.3.6.1.2.1.1.2.0': '.1.3.6.1.4.1.88.3.1',`
    `'.1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0': 558566090,`
    `'.1.3.6.1.2.1.1.4.0': "support@somewhere.ca",`
    `'.1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5.0': "NameOfSystem",`
    `'.1.3.6.1.2.1.1.6.0': "SomeHeadEnd, West Hinterlands, Canada",`
`}`

`def main(oids=testingOIDs):`
    `agent, port = createAgent( oids )`

`if __name__ == "__main__":`
    `reactor.IOCPReactor.callWhenRunning( main )`
    `reactor.IOCPReactor.run()`

Comment: Looks like the release candidate simply doesn't come with the `v4` subpackage. Perhaps you need to go back to 4.2.4 as a stable version, or check if you have everything that is mentioned at the [pysnmp download page](http://pysnmp.sourceforge.net/download.html).

Answer (score 0):

TwistedSNMP does not seem to be designed to work with PySNMP 4.x. Thus you should either use PySNMP 3.x / PySNMP SE or switch to PySNMP 4.x which has its own Twisted binding.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I used pysnmpSE 3.5.2 but still getting same error. I have modified the question and added code which I am trying to run

Comment: The traceback hints that you still have wrong pysnmp version. I'd advise uninstalling all pysnmp flavors from C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\ and do a clean PySNMP SE install. Or use PySNMP 4.x which is Twisted-friently.